# Generate text from other similar texts

Tags: text-processing, nlp

I'm looking for a piece of software, a script or whatever that could generate **text** based on **multiple other texts**.
That could be used for creating stories for instance. If the stories *used as the "base"* all follow the same **pattern**.

- **Input**: Multiple text files (.txt) containing English sentences.
- **Output**: A text file (.txt) same as above
- **OS**: UNIX, Windows
- **Pricing**: Free script, open-source if possible

The software would analyse the frequently used words, the average length, the structure, etc.
I guess there are existing scripts to do this kind of thing, but maybe not all together?

For instance, mixing text A and B would give C.

> **A:** The prince is called X. He is powerful and strong. He likes dragons and potatoes.
>
> **B:** The king Y is nice. He lives in Z. He thinks he could kill the dragon.
>
> **C:** The knight X' is feared. His name is X'. He kills dragons for a living.

I see how complex this is, but I've heard of a software that can summarize a text. This kind of thing is possible to do I guess. Using synonymes and stuf...
If nothing exists, I'll make it my project for this summer ^^

Comment: Could you please add some more details, e.g. specific requirements, and some background on how that should be used? That would significantly improve your chances to good answers. For a guide, you might refer to [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: For English language? Do you need it open source? Free?

Comment: You can generate realistic-looking nonsense in this form using N-grams, see a Ruby example here: http://www.sitepoint.com/natural-language-processing-ruby-n-grams/ - but if you also want such a system to track conceptual relationships and be consistent (always choosing a "knight" as the main character), then that is getting into NLP research and machine learning. It could be fun, but probably a lot of work.

Comment: NicolasRaoul: yes.
NeilSlater: Thanks! It looks interesting, I'll read this article :) I'm interested in NLP, but are there any libraries, or known-algorithms that could help me with that?

Comment: @mtefi: I don't know of any, but that does not mean much. I do however suspect that there is no generic script or library for you that will get you close to your goal in one step. This is a very hard problem in NLP. You *could* also look at ConceptNet as a starting data source. http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/

Comment: A key term for you to use in researching what you want to do is ***Markov chain***.